# Network seems to not work right away onCreate in Android

Tags: android, networking, emulation

I use Android Asynchronous Http Client http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

I need to retrieve some data when my app is created. The Internet permission is on. But the connection always failed with an error:

```
java.io.IOException: 
UnknownHostException exception: 
Unable to resolve host "google.com": No address associated with hostname
```

At first I thought that the problem is in DNS. I added `-dns-server 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4` as a default option. But I was still getting the error. I checked the browser application in my emulator and it works just fine. So the problem must be in my code. I tried to make a sleep for one second and the query worked. Obviously something isn't in a ready state when I execute the query.

Help me please to figure out what happens here. Thank you in advance.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //if I remove the sleep the http query fails
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.get("http://google.com/", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {
            System.out.println(statusCode);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] errorResponse, Throwable e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: try adding "www." to beginning of your url.

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work

Comment: are you adding related permissions in your manifest?

Comment: I think it's not the case. But yes, both `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` and `INTERNET` are there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that the internet connection isn't turned on immediately when the emulator starts.